# ¿Existe un Plugin para minería de datos con symfony?

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony2

Tengo un sistema desarrollado en `symfony v2.5`, y una base de datos `sql server` y quisiera saber si existe algún **plugin** para hacer un modulo de reportes con minería de datos,

*Por ejemplo:*

Tengo dos módulos de reportes conectados entre si que son: **Usuarios** y **Reportes de impresión**

Cuando yo genero un reporte en `Excel` de todos los reportes ingresados de impresión, en dicho reporte hago que obtenga el nombre del usuario que registró cada uno de ellos, pero quisiera tener algún **plugin** que me permita filtrar mas datos sobre el usuario, y quiero aplicarlo para muchos más módulos que tengo conectados entre sí.